# Adding rollback ability with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I have two collections, as follows:

```
let User = Schema({
    logID: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});
let Log = Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

I am performing the following transactions:

```
let currLog = await Log.findOne({"id": logID});
if(!currLog) throw new Error("No such log is there");
let newUser = await User.save(payload);
let updatedLog = await currLog.users.push(newUser._id);
currLog.update();
```

So, if for some reason, LOG is not updated, The new user should be rolledback, as in deleted. 
How can this be achieved exactly using mongoose?
I have looked in to the following resources:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/
https://github.com/anand-io/mongoose-transaction
But finding it difficult to implement the functionality.
Since, in my case, the data from the first transaction is being used in the second one (**newUser._id**).

Comment: add callback for update and see if its updating or not incase any error then delete the newUser with its _id

Comment: what about the other case, if I deleted a user and then while popping it out from Log, I get an error.  How do I revert that change (as in revert the remove operations)?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: the flow will be like, first pull the id out of the Log and if it's successful then remove the user. In this way, if somehow pull out faces error you can set the id again later maintaining some kind of flags in the user schema.